# ios ble connect multiple devices with tableview in Swift fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

i want to show two section about not connected and connected
my swift is not very good.

this is my code
https://www.codepile.net/pile/vNYKLZ6L

and  When I run this, it crashes here
`let peripheral = self.peripherals[indexPath.row]`

> fatal error: Index out of range

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Connect to device where the peripheral is connected
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BlueCell") as! PeripheralTableViewCell
    let peripheral = self.peripherals[indexPath.row]
    //let RSSI = self.RSSIs[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        if peripheral.name == nil {
           cell.peripheralLabel?.text = "nil"
        } else {
           cell.peripheralLabel?.text = peripheral.name
        }
    } else {
       if connectPeripherals.count == 0 {
          cell.peripheralLabel?.text = "nil"
       } else {            
          cell.peripheralLabel?.text = self.connectPeripherals[indexPath.row].name
       }
    }

    //cell.rssiLabel.text = "RSSI: \(RSSI)"
    print("tableview連線有\(connectPeripherals.count)個")
    print("tableview未連線有\(peripherals.count)個")

    return cell
}
```

here is numberOfRowsInSection function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0{
        return self.peripherals.count
    } else {
        return self.connectPeripherals.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `numberOfRowsInSection` function

Comment: As per your code shared in the link, It shouldn't have crashed with Index out of range, instead it could have crashed on the line "let peripheral = self.peripherals[indexPath.row]" because only under section == 0 you have to use it as you mentioned in "numberOfRowsAtSection". Try adding the line inside "if indexPath.section == 0{" block

Comment: That is your numberOfSections, not your numberOfRowsInSection. Also you should edit your question to add code, don't put it in a comment.

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see `peripherals` is on section_0 and `connectPeripherals` is on section_1, so you might re-organize your code in this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BlueCell") as! PeripheralTableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let peripheral = self.peripherals[indexPath.row]
        cell.peripheralLabel?.text = peripheral.name != nil ? peripheral.name : "nil"
    } else {
        let connectedPeripheral = self.connectPeripherals[indexPath.row]
        cell.peripheralLabel?.text = connectedPeripheral.name != nil ? connectedPeripheral.name : "nil"
    }

    print("tableview連線有\(connectPeripherals.count)個")
    print("tableview未連線有\(peripherals.count)個")
    return cell
}
```